# If statement in Java

Tags: java

I need to make this method, write a method reportInStock() to print to the terminal window whether the CD is in stock or whether it has been borrowed. If it has been borrowed it should also report the name of the borrower

I wrote this code, but no matter what, it always shows the cd is available when I run the print terminal window.

```
 public void borrower(String nameOfBorrower)
/**
 * 
 */
{
   borrower = nameOfBorrower;
   borrowed = true;
   inStock = false;
}

public void returned()
/**
 * 
 */
{
   borrower = "";
   borrowed = false;
   inStock = true;
}

public boolean isBorrowed()
/**
 * 
 */
{
   return borrowed;
}

public void reportInStock()
/**
 * 
 */
{
    if(inStock = false)
    {
        System.out.println("This CD has been borrowed;" + personName);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This CD is available");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `if(inStock = false)` do?

Comment: `inStock = false` sets the variable `inStock` to `false`. `inStock == false` compares the value of the expression `inStock` to the value of the expression `false`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(inStock = false)
```

This is wrong - you're assigning to inStock, not comparing! You should instead use

```
if(inStock == false)
```

or the shorter form

```
if(!inStock)
```

Comment: wow, how the hell didnt i see that, feel like a right idiot now. thank you so much

Comment: @user2925919 you might want to have a look at FindBugs (http://findbugs.sourceforge.net). It should warn you about those kinds of errors (e.g. http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#QBA_QUESTIONABLE_BOOLEAN_ASSIGNMENT).

Comment: Why would this answer get a Downvote? Someone bitter? Some compensation.

Answer (score 0):

inStock = false looks suspicious :)
Should it be == ?