# Java counting method?

Tags: java

I need to write some code that will count the amount of times someone has borrowed a CD. I tried doing some but just failed and don't have a clue any more.

Like I said, stuck again on something that is probably simple to do:

```
  public void borrower(String nameOfBorrower)
/**
 * 
 */
{
   borrower = nameOfBorrower;
   borrowed = true;
   inStock = false;
}

public void returned()
/**
 * 
 */
{
   borrower = "";
   borrowed = false;
   inStock = true;
}

public boolean isBorrowed()
/**
 * 
 */
{
   return borrowed;
}

public void reportInStock()
/**
 * 
 */
{
    if(inStock == false)
    {
        System.out.println("This CD has been borrowed;" + personName);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This CD is available");
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, mind elaborating?

Comment: Do you ever change `inStock` to `false`?

Comment: Show was what you have tried, and why you are confused that it doesn't work.  We will not do it for you

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624198/if-statement-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want to get how many times a CD was borrowed? or who borrowed how many times?
to check how many times the CD was borrowed
in your

```
public void borrower(String nameOfBorrower)
{
  borrower = nameOfBorrower;
  borrowed = true;
  inStock = false;
  times++;
}

public int GetTimes()
{
   return times;
}
```

Comment: how many times it has been borrow overall

Comment: I have added my answer plz check.

Comment: did you initiallized times as int times=0;?

Comment: its okay, i sorted it out, had add few things but it works now, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

That depend and the case what you want to analysis, the exact CD o just title of it.

For Title we have a many to many relation you should try to design a class that could represent that state.

new BorrowTransaction(Person).borrow(CD);

The borrow method should persist the data about who borrow what.

Then you your CD class you could have object called `CDStats` that contain information about borrows and etc.

For unique CD case is quite simple. You should add a field to the class that will store the value and increment it each time by one when a borrower is assigned to it.